# Presentation of $C_p\ :\ C_q$ , where $p,q$ are primes and $q|p-1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

There are the following presentations of some groups $C_p\ :\ C_q$ :

```
gap> StructureDescription(f/[a^23,b^11,b*a*b^(-1)*a^(-2)]);
"C23 : C11"
gap> StructureDescription(f/[a^29,b^7,b*a*b^(-1)*a^(-7)]);
"C29 : C7"
gap> StructureDescription(f/[a^43,b^7,b*a*b^(-1)*a^(-4)]);
"C43 : C7"
```

So, it seems that $ < a^p , b^q , bab^{-1}a^k >$ is a presentation for $C_p\ :\ C_q$ for some $k$. Since GAP can produces an error like this :

```
gap> StructureDescription(f/[a^23,b^11,b*a*b^(-1)*a^21]);
Error, exponent too large, Modified Todd-Coxeter aborted in
  ApplyRel2( app2, triple[2], triple[1] ); called from
EnterDeduction(  ); called from
LoopOverAllCosets(  ); called from
AugmentedCosetTableRrs( G, table, 0, "_x" ) called from
RelatorMatrixAbelianizedSubgroupRrs( G, H ) called from
AbelianInvariantsSubgroupFpGroup( G, H ) called from
...  at line 215 of *stdin*
```

it seems to be better to choose a negative value for $k$, as it is the case for the presentations above.

> Question : For which $k<-1$ is $< a^p,b^q,bab^{-1}a^k >$ is a presentation for $C_p\ :\ C_q$ with primes $p,q$ and $q|p-1$ ? In particular, which is the largest such $k$ doing the job ?

Comment: What is f? I took a guess that it was defined as a two-generator free group, but your example then seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: Yes, f is a freegroup with generators $a$ and $b$. My question is how I find $k$ in general.

Comment: The map $a\mapsto a^k$ must be an automorphism of the cyclic group $\langle a\rangle$, so $k$ just needs to be relatively prime to $p$.

Comment: This is not enough. For example, $1$ is relatively prime to every $p$, but setting $k=1$ will make the group collapse. You need to choose $k$ to be an element of order $q$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, to make sure that $a\mapsto a^k$ has order $q$.

Comment: Moreover, from a theoretical point of view, it is irrelevant whether $k$ is negative or not: since $a^p=1$, the value of $k$ can be taken modulo $p$. 
I'm not sure why GAP returned an error in your second example.

If you really want $k$ to be close to $0$ (not modulo $p$), then this is related to the question of finding a small primitive root of $p$. There is a large litterature on this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n
It is not easy to give an explicit one, but a search usually produces one quite quickly.

Comment: The notation $C_p\ :\ C_q$ is new to me. I know what the groups either side of the colon are but I don't know what the colon itself means here. It's not exactly something one can search for easily. Please would someone explain it to me?

Comment: @Shaun `StructureDescription` uses `:` for a semidirect product - see its documentation at https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X8199B74B84446971

Comment: Thank you, @AlexanderKonovalov :)